# How to move the awk outputs to a single folder?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to move awk output files in to a single folder.The name of each  output file should be the name of the input file. I used the following program. But this program saves each output file as "out" and its directory name is the name of input file. How can I change the following code to save the outputs in to a single folder with input filenames.

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do mkdir "$i"_dir;  awk -f script.awk "$i" > "$i"_dir/out; done
```

Comment: What should the output files be called?  Or should the output for multiple files be in a single `out` file?

Comment: output files should be the name of file names. In my program, all output files are named as out instead of filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do 
    awk -f script.awk "$i" > out; 
done
```

should work, or inline

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do awk -f script.awk "$i" > out; done
```

Your output file will be named simply "out" in your current directory.

Also note that this neither makes the directories, nor stores the output in them.  If you need to make the directories, but not write to them, you'll have to add the `mkdir` command back.

**EDIT**

Per your updated question, you'll first want to make an output directory, lets call it `foo`.

```
mkdir foo
```

So now the directory structure should look like

```
/path/to/your/base-folder/
                        ./file/   <-- The directory in which your .txt files reside
                        ./foo/    <-- Your output folder
```

Then, from inside that base folder you can run the following:

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do awk -f script.awk "$i" > foo/"$i"; done
```

Or if you want file extensions on your output files:

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do awk -f script.awk "$i" > foo/"$i".txt; done
```

Comment: `out` will only contain the results of the last file, as each iteration will overwrite the results of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

jedwards,

you must add **>>** in place of **>** if you want all the output. otherwise you will just have the last iteration of the cycle.

```
for i in file/*.txt;  do awk -f script.awk "$i" >> out; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the output redirection outside the loop.

```
mkdir dir
for i in file/*.txt; do
  awk -f script.awk "$i"
done > dir/out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in file/*.txt; #get a value for "i"
 do mkdir "$i"_dir; #create a folder called *value for i"_dir
 awk -f script.awk "$i" > "$i"_dir/out; done #save the output to the created
                                             #directory saving only the last
                                             #iteration of the cycle, as @farid said.
```

Try this

`for i in file/*.txt;  do mkdir dir;  awk -f script.awk "$i" >> dir/out; done`

You can change the desired directory name by changing from `dir`, to `anything`

`for i in file/*.txt;  do mkdir anything;  awk -f script.awk "$i" >> anything/out; done`